# Installing software into computer using liveUSB (but not into liveUSB)

Tags: boot, steam

My goal is to install Steam into work computer for which I do not have root access, however have physical access.

I do not want to change root password (unless it would be possible to set it back somehow with no record of changing it).

It would be great if LiveUSB could be used to access computers hard drive (which is unencrypted) and install it from there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a live USB system to clear or change the root password of your computer. The password is stored encrypted in the file /etc/shadow so, you can restore it to whatever you have at the moment after you finish. You don't need to know it, just keep the encrypted value for later.
[These instructions](https://computersecuritystudent.com/UNIX/UBUNTU/1204/lesson5/index.html) use a virtual machine, but you can follow the same steps using a live USB.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into your LiveUSB, mount the system partition.

From there, get the package source and install it through dpkg with the --root=[directory] option, to specify a specific install dir (which would be on your work partition).

I don't think you'd have to chroot into the system partition. You might want to `chown` the files to allow your user to execute steam.